# Manage registered GCM services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, intercom

I'm new to Google clound messaging and need a hint.

I registered two services on [Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue) when I was enabling push notifications on [Intercom](https://developers.intercom.com/v2.0/docs/android-gcm-push-notifications).

- AppName-Beta
- AppName-Release

Now I want to delete one of them and rename the other, because I learned that I just need one. Unfortunately I cannot find the overview screen from my registered google clound messaging services. Does anybody know where to manage them? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head to your [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and choose the hamburger menu from the upper-left corner:
[image: Google Dev Console]

Select "Manage Resources" from the "IAM & Admin" menu:
[image: Manage Resources menu]

Delete the extraneous project:
[image: Delete extraneous project]

Comment: Thanks @Skyler for your help. I had choose my organisation in the dropdown-menu above the list.